# How can I iterate over an array which is inside Json body in Azure Logic App?

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

This is the sample JSON
{
"status": "SUCCESS",
"data": [List of objects to be iterated over]
}
I want to fetch this data array object since I' would be using it as a body for another API call

Comment: Could you please be more specific what exactly you looking for whether you want to pass the complete ``data`` array as a body to another API or you want to pass only some of the objects under ``data`` array as a body to another API . 

Would be more helpful if you could help us with sample json to test it further.

Comment: Hey @VenkateshDodda-MT , The data is an array of objects, which I want to iterate over in a for each loop. Sample JSON: 
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "data": [
        {
           "name" : "Ajinkya",
    "address" : "Mumbai"
        },
        {
           "name" : "john",
    "address" : "Pune"
        }
    ],
    "successful": true
}
as you can see data is an array of objects i want to iterate over, and with each object I want to call a post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used HTTP request as trigger in our logic app ,where json as payload.

Use COMPOSE in for each  to pull the `Name, Address` values.

You can have the rest-api call(using HTTP) in the same for-each so that each object will be passed as body to post request.

[image]